# D3 filter() after a selectAll()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I'm trying to understand the beatiful library D3. 
Really – I don't understand why the following lines do not work. 
**The code should fill only a few of the cirlces in a special color.**

```
<svg>
<g id="row_1"> ... </g>
<g id="row_1"> ... </g>
<g id="row_3"> ... </g>
    <circle cx="16.887" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="33.574" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="50.262" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="66.949" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="167.074" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="183.762" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="333.387" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="316.699" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="300.199" cy="334.101" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="266.637" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="250.137" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
    <circle cx="216.762" cy="333.923" r="6.268"/>
</g>
</svg>


<script>
var i;
var identifierID;
var svg = d3.select("svg");  

for (i=0; i<=20; i++){
   identifierID = "#row_"+i;
   svg.select(identifierID).selectAll("circle")
   .filter(function(d){ return d == 12; }).style("fill","blue") *//the value 12 is a example*
}
</script>
```

The code looks like (circle = ° )

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° (°) <-special color

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° (°) <-special color

° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° (°) <-special color

But it does not work with the function filter (after all without it does^^).
It would be great, if someone could help me!
Regards

Comment: `d` would be the data bound to the circle, but you have not bound any data so `d` will be `undefined` so all elements will return falsey in the filter and you will get an empty selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each 'd' object you are passing to your filter holds all the properties of that circle.  If you want to filter on a specific index, you can pass two arguments to filter:

```
.filter(function(d, i) // i is the index
    return i === 12;
});
```

if you want to filter on a property of d, you need to access it with dot notation or bracket notation.

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, `d` is the bound datum, not the properties of the circle.

Comment: @JonahWilliams thanks :) ** but one more question:** There is no way to say index i is i+1 in the loop – like this:
      
     `i=i+1;
     .filter(function(d, i)
        return i === 12;
});` So the counter from the filter function is unchangeable/fix?